# SWIG and C++: extending a class from another module

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am facing a cross-mudule problems with SWIG/C++ that I can't manage to resolve.

Let's consider a module M1 containing a class C with a set of it's methods. This module is generated from C++ via SWIG, _M1 being the corresponding shared library.

M1.py

```
class CL(_object):
    def Sth(*args): return _M1.CL_Sth(*args)
```

I'd like to extend this CL class with an additional method SthElse. I know the following would work if the extension is done in the same module:

CL.i

```
%{
#include "CL.h"
%}
%include "CL.h"
%extend CL {
    void SthElse() { return; }
}
```

However my concern is that the extension can not be done in the M1 module, it has to be done externally in module M2.

I first tried to do the following:

M2.i

```
%module M2
%{
#include "CL.h"
%}
%include "CL.i"

%extend CL {
  void SthElse() { return; }
}
```

This lead to a M2.py creation, with the CL methods and the new one in it. The problem is that the CL is no more M1's CL but M2.CL:

M2.py

```
class CL(_object):
    def Sth(*args): return _M2.CL_Sth(*args)
    def SthElse(*args): return _M2.CL_SthElse(*args)
```

Calling CL.Sth() then logically fails as Sth is not defined in M2.

Then I went to:

M2.i

```
%module M2
%{
#include "CL.h"
%}
%import(module="M1") "CL.h"

%extend CL {
  void SthElse() { return; }
}
```

This makes an "import M1" instruction appear in the generated M2.py but no extension method, so that

```
cl = CL()
cl.SthElse()
```

would fail on an attribute error.

From now on I am a bit lost and have no more ideas. Swig documentation has not been helpful (or I haven't been able to find the right chapter).

Comment: I'm sorry, "Hi" has disappeared from my message. So hi :) And thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to enable the director swig feature ? See documentation [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_directors), and in particular [enabling directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn33)